# Can we use Moto G2 with google Cardboard

Tags: motorola-moto-g2

Can I use Moto G2 with Google Cardboard. I just want to experience Virtual reality in a cheapest way possible. I've a Moto G2, So I was wondering If I can use Moto G2 with Google Cardbaord. If anybody has used it then please suggest me, What kind of stuff I would be able to see and what I won't be able to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your phone should fit. Only you will not be able to use ring button because moto g2 doesn't have magnetic sensor.

Comment: Would it affect much. Gyroscope is there in my device I've checked it.

Comment: The button is rarely used in vr apps,  most vr games needs to connect games controller,  so it  wouldn't affect much.

Comment: I have Moto G2 2014 model and it has magnetic sensor. Only thing is the pixels are visible in VR when it is zoomed.